# Delete workbook permanently after expiry in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CommintSuicide()
With ThisWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If .Path <> vbNullString Then
        .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        Kill .FullName
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
```

End Sub

"I need to put expiry date in this code which should delete workbook including vba code on particular date automatically"

Comment: If .Path <> vbNullString and date() > expireDate then... Don't forget to close workbook first.

Comment: It is not working automatically, when I run macro while in workbook then it close and delete workbook otherwise it stays normal. Here it is :

Comment: It is not working automatically, when I run macro while in workbook then it close and delete workbook otherwise it stays normal.   
I am trying to write a code so that on expiry date when user try to open this workbook it will close and deleted automatically.

Comment: Hmm try putting code into workbook_open. Also, I am a bit confused which workbook you are trying to delete XD

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. There is only one workbook in which I have  labels, check boxes, user forms etc. I just want to make sure the same workbook work for few weeks on trial basis and should be deleted by itself automatically without giving any alert or message.

Comment: Ok. I meant, from your code, you're deleting the workbook then closing it which makes no sense. But yea, put your code inside workbook_open of the workbook you want to delete.

Comment: Could you please help me with this code :                                         Sub CommintSuicide()
    With ThisWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If .Path <> vbNullString and date() > 17/08/2015 Then
            .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
            Kill .FullName
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub

Comment: This is the same thing I tried doing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012834/delete-excel-file) but failed XD

Comment: I think there is a confusion : let me clarify : I have a work book named "ABX". This workbook is saved in documents folder. I want to set trial period of about 20 days so that after 20 days instead of asking for renewal it just get deleted by itself permanently. Is it possible in vba?

Comment: I think it is but I failed ;_;